# Signal Ground near Earth POE

Tags: pcb-design, ground, poe

I have Earth Ground 48V poured around the components before our diode array. I have three seperate ground planes, one for Earth, one for our POE components before the transformer, and our signal 5V ground. I have to edit this board to bring our daughter board onto it, with a 5V 40 pin connector. This connector has to come close to the Earth ground, as I show in the image. Is there any thing to look out for when moving this ground past our inductor and close to the ground for 48V?[image]